# Blender Clay Strips Brush Tool only add on the edges of surfaces?

Tags: brushes

When I try to use the clay strips it only adds on the edge of the circle brush instead of center. I tried some fixes but nothing works.

[image: Clay On Edge instead of the center]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by Checking if the scale was negative, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and applied the scale in object mode. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Checking if? It is negative, your screenshot shows that ;)